# Where was Saint Patrick of Ireland born?

Tags: saint, st-patrick

There are claims that his birthplace is Scotland, England or even Wales.

Answer (score 3):

**Where saint Patrick of Ireland was born?**

The question as to where St. Patrick was born is up to debate, but many believe it was somewhere in Strathclyde.

> Patrick (Patricius or Padrig) was born around 386 AD to wealthy parents. Patrick’s birthplace is in fact debatable, with **many believing that he was born in the still Welsh-speaking Northern Kingdom of Strathclyde** of Romano-Brythonic stock, at Bannavem Taberniae. Others consider his birthplace to be in the south of Wales around the Severn estuary, or at St. Davids in Pembrokeshire, the tiny city of St Davids sitting directly on the seagoing missionary and trade routes to and from Ireland. His birth name was Maewyn Succat.
>
> Not much is known about his early life, but it is believed he was captured and sold into slavery with “many thousands of people” by a group of Irish marauders that raided his family estate. - [St Patrick – The most celebrated Welshman in America?](https://www.historic-uk.com/HistoryUK/HistoryofWales/St-Patrick-The-most-celebrated-Welshman-in-America/)

[image]

[Kingdom of Strathclyde at its largest extent, circa 940 A.D.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingdom_of_Strathclyde)

Comment: Thank you a lot. This is a high-quality answer. I haven’t even thought that someone would send me even a map.